# open camera using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I want to use `intent` to open `camera` in **Android** .

I used the following **code** but when i press the `button` (whose action is `onclick()` function the app closes on itself .

```
 public void onclick(int actionCode){
     Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
} 
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) { 
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager(); 
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action); 
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY); 
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

If someone can help me .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
File destination;
Uri selectedImage;
public static String selectedPath1 = "NONE";
private static final int PICK_Camera_IMAGE = 2;
private static final int SELECT_FILE1 = 1;
public static Bitmap bmpScale;
public static String imagePath;



    mcamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mcamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String name = dateToString(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");
            destination = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), name + ".jpg");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(destination));
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_Camera_IMAGE);

        }
    });

    // ......................gallery_function..........//
    mgallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mgallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            openGallery(SELECT_FILE1);
        }
    });
```

for intent
// .........................Gallery function.................//

```
    public void openGallery(int SELECT_FILE1) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file to upload "),
            SELECT_FILE1);

}
```

//............ intent .........

```
                // ..................
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    Uri selectedImageUri = null;
    String filePath = null;
    switch (requestCode) {
    case SELECT_FILE1:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1) {
                selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImage);
                // mimagepath.setText(selectedPath1);
                // Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "" + selectedPath1 + "",
                // 500).show();

                if (selectedPath1 != null) {

                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    // image path `String` where your image is located
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedPath1, options);



                // Log.d("setpath ", "setpath " + selectedPath1);
                ;

            }
        }

        break;
    case PICK_Camera_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(destination);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();

            // Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "" + imagePath +
            // "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: @rishi-what are selectedPath1&selectedImage.....Also what is the methos getPath(selectedImage) because there's no such internal method as getpath()

Comment: selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImage); this get the path of image

Comment: @Rishi Gautam - What's the used of PICK_Camera_IMAGE = 2?

Answer (score 5):

try this code

```
public static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1;//firstly define this 



Intent photo= new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    startActivityForResult(photo, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Comment: nice simple `code` for start working with camera in `Android` .

Answer (score 2):

The parameter passed to an "on-click" method is of type `View` not `int` as you show.

According to [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-the-camera/) tutorial your onClick method should be as follows:

```
public void onclick( View v ){
     Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}
```

Where `CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST` is defined as (although I'm not quite sure why you would need to statically hard-code this value in your application):

```
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;
```

## Update

`CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST` is used to uniquely identify the result being returned to `onActivityResult`.  Multiple `startActivityForResult`requests could be outstanding at one time.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) { 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            tv.setText("Got picture!");
            imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageBitmap(imageData);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            tv.setText("Cancelled");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: @HeatfanJohn-could you also tell how to display full sized image not just the small bitmap in an imageview without saving it

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at this code, this is working fine with me

```
//define the file-name to save photo taken by Camera activity
fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
//create parameters for Intent with filename
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image capture by camera");
imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

also apply this method to read image when you taken the image from camera.

```
    //handling intent responses
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
      try {
        if (bitmap != null) {bitmap.recycle();}

        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(imageUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        imageUriString = cursor.getString(column_index);

        getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        try {
            bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);
            imageButtonPictureShop.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

//              this.uploadImage();
                this.executeMultipartPost();
//                this.uploadFile(imageUriString);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(e.getMessage() != null)Log.e("Exception"  , e.getMessage());
                else Log.e("Exception"  , "Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

```
      } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if(e.getMessage() != null)Log.e("Exception"  , e.getMessage());
        else Log.e("Exception"  , "Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question old and answered, but for those who are asking how to get the image file ?
heres the solution.

```
String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/DCIM/Camera";

File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles()

String ImagePath = files[ file.files-1 ].getAbsolutePath();

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName); 
ivImage.setImageBitmap( bmp );
```

Also you don't need to add Camera permissions on your Manifest file.

-Cheers and vote up if this help you

-Happy Codings..

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to start camera from your Android app:
just write two lines code in **onClick** method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST );
```

Add one constant field in your class (you can use any random number instead of 7)

```
private int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found this solution. Just to make things clear I created an entire app for this question which serves the purpose of opening the camera clicking a photo and setting the image as the ImageBitmap of an ImageView. The code asked in this question starts at the second block i.e. the setView() method which is below the onCreate() method following which we have the onActivityResult() method

Here is a demo of the app.

[image: Demonstration]

Below I have Attached the MainActivity.java file

```
package com.cr7.opencamera;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonCaptureImageFromCamera;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private ImageView imageViewCameraImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Button that will open the camera
        buttonCaptureImageFromCamera = findViewById(R.id.buttonCaptureImageFromCamera);
        // ImageView that will store the image
        imageViewCameraImage = findViewById(R.id.imageViewCameraImage);
        askPermission();
    }
```

Here imageUri is a global variable so that it can be used in the onActivityResult() method

```
    // Sets OnClickListener for the button if storage permission is given
    private void setView() {
        buttonCaptureImageFromCamera.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
            // Create parameters for Intent with filename
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image capture by camera");
            imageUri =
                    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            values);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1231);
        });
    }
```

This is the onActivityResult method. Here I've used imageUri i.e. the global variable of type Uri which was initialized in the OnClickListener of the button in the setView() method above.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1231 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                try {
                    // Creating a Bitmap with the image Captured
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);
                    // Setting the bitmap as the image of the
                    imageViewCameraImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                if (e.getMessage() != null)
                    Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                else
                    Log.e("Exception", "Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Remaining code...

```
    // Asking user for storage permission
    public void askPermission() {
        // Checking if the permissions are not granted.
        if (
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // If not granted requesting Read and  Write storage
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, /*You can ask for multiple request by adding
            more permissions to the string*/new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 60);
        } else {
            // If permissions are granted we proceed by setting an OnClickListener for the button
            // which helps the user pick the image
            setView();
        }
    }

    // This method is called after the permissions have been asked i.e. the dialog that says
    // allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // Now by default we assume that the permission has not been granted
        boolean allPermissionsGranted = false;
        // Now we check if the permission was granted
        if ( requestCode == 60 && grantResults.length > 0) {
            // If all the permissions are granted allPermissionsGranted is set to true else false
            allPermissionsGranted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    &&
                    grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
        // If permissions are granted we call the setView Method which prompts the user to pick
        // an Image either by the clicking it now or picking from the gallery
        if ( allPermissionsGranted ) {
            setView();
        }
    }
}
```

These blocks of code are in sequence i.e. if you merge all these blocks you get the complete MainActivity.java class.

If you wan to Implement this app you need yo create a layout file with an ImageView with an id "imageViewCameraImage"and a button with an id "buttonCaptureImageFromCamera".

Hope this helps. I know this is long and I'm making it longer by writing this.
Regards,
Joel