# How to open Android front camera intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, front-camera

I want to open the front camera in nexus 7 but I am not to open it is always opening back camera then Manually I am selecting the front cam through my android program how can I open always front camera first I have tried [This links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799818/open-camera-using-intent) but not working for me.

@present I am using below code to open camera and take the image

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 102;
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
                        intent.putExtra ("camerasensortype", 2);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    }
```

Comment: If you launch a third-party camera app, the user and that app choose what camera to use, not you. If you need control over this, implement the camera code yourself in your own app.

Comment: I am implementing my own app only, just I am learning how to open front camera on button click, as I am new to Android development

Answer (score 3):

There you go :) 
working on 5X (7.0), MI3 (6.0), S3 Neo (4.4)

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
                            launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            launchIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                            launchIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
                            launchIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

Comment: This I have tried like Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
      intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
      startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE); but its not working