# how to open camera in onshowfilechooser android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

I am creating a webview app. I want file chooser functionality from the webview. I successfully created the file chooser but it opens file manager to choose file. Now I want camera to be open when user clicks on choose file.

Comment: what intent you are passing, when you click on choose file

Comment: I think you should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799818/open-camera-using-intent